# compile c++ code in c mode

Tags: c++, c, c-mode

Following is my code saved as .cpp file and .c file

in .c it compiled fine, but threw the following error in .cpp

```
test.cpp:6: error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long
test.cpp:6: error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long
```

```
#include< stdio.h>

int main()
{

char str[2][2]= { "12", "12"};
int i;

for(i=0; i<2; i++)
printf("%d %s\n", i, str[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Is there any compiler directive or anything so that the c++ compiler takes this as C code itself.

I tried, extern "C", which didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it won't help your problem, you can select language to compile. With gcc it's -x flag, that needs to be followed by language. Like gcc -x c something.cpp ... will use c compiler to compile.

Comment: This solved my problem with the code shared. This would make my whole code to compile as C program. Is there any way I can make a part of my code to compile in C mode.

Comment: As far as I know, only if you split your program in multiple modules (files).

Answer (score 14):

The character string "12" hold 3 places in C++ (In C too, BTW). You need one more char for the terminating `'\0'`.

```
char str[2][3]= { "12", "12"};
```

Answer (score 10):

This would 'fit'

```
char str[2][2] = {
  { '1', '2' },
  { '1', '2' }
};
```

But you want this: https://ideone.com/wZB8F

```
char str[2][3]= { "12", "12"};
```

**Otherwise, there is no room for the terminating `null` character**

Equivalent:

```
char str[2][3]= { { '1', '2', '\0' },
                  { '1', '2', '\0' } };
```

Comment: In the first example, there is one level of braces too much!

Comment: @bitmask: sorry, missed that, fixed

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a stricter language than C. The problem is that you create an array containing of arrays of two characters, then assign each sub-array three characters (the sequence `'1'`, `'2'` and the string terminator `'\0'`).

The array should be declared like this:

```
char str[2][3]= { "12", "12"};
```

The C compiler doesn't flag for this, and skips the string-terminator, so your `printf` statement will most likely print garbage after the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include< stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    char str[][3]= { "12","12"}; 
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<2; i++) 
    {
        printf("%d %s\n", i, str[i]);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

is the version that will work in C++....